# Do I have the right supply list to start my under cabinet LED project?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, transformer

Thanks for all the recent help on here. I am gathering supplies for an under cabinet RBGW LED project (US).

So far I have:

1. [RBGW 12v LED Strip Lights](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01D1I50UW)
2. [100-240v to 12v Transformer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0793T7YXK)
3. [Wireless Controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075ZQ73ZD)
4. [Leviton 1451-2 Grounded Toggle Switch 120v, 15amp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001E170SY)
5. Standard 14/2 wiring

My plan is to tap off an existing switch in my kitchen and add an extra light switch. I'll use the 14/2 wiring to connect the new switch to the transformer, hardwiring. Then, I'll use the 14/2 wiring to connect the transformer to the controller. The controller will then connect to the LED strips.

Do I have the right idea and right set up? If so, the only other pieces I could use some guidance on are:

1. Do I need to use different wiring between the transformer and controller (I was going to use 14/2, but it doesn't look like the transformer has a "ground output", so I am not sure what the wire I should technically use is called).
2. Is there a certain name for the wire that would connect the controller to the LED strips? I am not sure what wiring to use there.

Thanks!

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: Is this circuit part of the circuit that supplies the countertop receptacles?

Comment: It is not. The countertop receptacles are on a 20 amp circuit. The light switch I am going to tap into is alongside the countertop receptacles, but it is on a 15 amp circuit and controls the pendant lights.

Answer (score 2):

After the 12v transformer/power supply, 14/2 wiring is overkill for low-voltage LED applications as these are carrying a very low wattage. Commonly used wiring is 18 or 20 gauge stranded copper which is basically speaker wire. This can be found in 2, 3, or 4-conductor cables depending on your LED signal needs.

I've been using some 3-wire 18 gauge cable with UV-resistant outer jacket for LED Christmas light shows. There are a lot of different options available on Amazon or your hardware store. You can probably even find some "extension cables" with your LED pin connectors already crimped on - if not you'll have to crimp or solder the connections yourself.

Comment: This is part of a perimeter wiring system (light switch to the transformer). so 14 awg is the minimum size by code if a 15 amp circuit if a 20 amp circuit code is 12awg. advising otherwise would be non code compliant. Yes inside a fixture smaller wires are allowed but not in this case unless everything is contained in a listed enclosure. Cordage for permanent wiring is also a code violation.

Comment: I think Fredric means 14/2 is overkill for the low voltage side of the transformer, but an edit might make that more clear